# How to add fixed width image view in center horizontal using constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

[image]

Hello guys, I need to add 2 fixed width and height imageview in to center of screen using constraint layout how we can achieve something like this.

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.profile.view.UserDetailsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/you_are"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25" />


    <CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_farmer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profilewithimage"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#e4e4e4"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/iv_prof"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_label" />

    <CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_prof"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profilewithimage"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#e4e4e4"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_farmer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_label" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i am trying this but views are not centerd.

Comment: Hi, where are you stuck in creating the same? Add your xml layout here, so that we can help you.

Comment: added xml layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have updated your xml code. Please try with this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="You are"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/iv_farmer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25" />


    <CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_farmer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profilewithimage"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#e4e4e4"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_prof"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_prof"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profilewithimage"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#e4e4e4"
        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_farmer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: usage of   `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25"` really helping

Answer (score 1):

In your first `CircularImageView` there's a problem with your right constraint:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/iv_prof"
```

This should be constrained to the left of `iv_prof`:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_prof"
```

If you want the to be closer together in the center then change the style of the chain to `packed` by adding this attribute to the first `CircularImageView`:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

To center the `Views` vertically in the parent you need to constraint the top and bottom of each `View` to the top and bottom of the parent respectively.

Also you're using left/right constraints for some `Views` and start/end for others. Try using just one set of them across the whole layout.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using `bias`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/weather_logo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```